# Scrapy - Selenium TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: selenium, scrapy

I get the following error:

```
start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

when I run:

```
class CramoSpider(Spider):
    name = 'cramo'
    allowed_domains = ['www.cramo.ee']

    def start_requests(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Laptop/chromedriver')
        self.driver.get('https://www.cramo.ee/et/rentimine/hinnakiri')

    def parse_book(self, response):
        pass
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: this is not a good way to use selenium with scrapy, Your Error is that `start_requests` must return atleast one request, your driver will open the website but then you will get this error

Comment: agree with above comment, is there a reason this needs to be a scrapy spider?

Comment: When using Selenium and Scrapy, better use https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium